# Java: Console output in same line after user inputs and hits 'Enter'

Tags: java, input, console, output, java.util.scanner

I am asking the user to input an integer through a console.
Is it possible to output in the same line if the user has hit 'Enter' after the input?

Comment: You want to look for the JLine library.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but is there any solution without using a library that has to be downloaded first? I mean, using solely the standard libraries?

Comment: No way. At least not a portable one. If you're on Linux, you may want to have a look into stty.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print(value) maybe?

Comment: After reading the input, the user hits 'Enter' which transfers the output of Syste.out.print(value) to be printed in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the print the users input in the console or do you want to reprint the question you asked the user in order to obtain another value.

Either way, have a look at the do while construction and check if the input given is the input you expected. Otherwise ask the question again.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the value that the user inputted is of expected value or similar. We can simplify and suppose that the user inputs an integer within a certain range as required.

Neither it matters what I intend to output. I just want to output a string in the same line where the user inputted his value.

So the issue here is how to avoid the skip to the next line, since the user ends the process of inputting by hitting the 'Enter' key, and continue printing in the same line.

Comment: This is probably impossible since if you cannot override the enter command that triggers the user input. However you can use System.out.print() instead of the println to omit the newline.